# Using a custom classloader with Spring's ComponentScan and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring

I want to create multiple application contexts in my Tomcat application.

Some of these application contexts have the same package and class names, but they all refer to different jars.

For example:

> application0 use service.jar, model.jar
>
> application1 use service-a.jar, model-a.jar
>
> application2 use service-b.jar, model-b.jar

application0 context is OK because is in orign project.

I reference some web page to custom application1, I use my custom classloader to start applicationContext.

```
File file0 = new File("D://git/project1/service-a.jar");
File file1 = new File("D://git/project1/modele-a.jar");

// convert the file to URL format
URL url0 = file0.toURI().toURL();
URL url1 = file1.toURI().toURL();

List<URL> urls = new LinkedList<>();

List<File> libs = listFilesForFolder(new File("D://protal//apache-tomcat-8.0.39//lib"));
for(File lib : libs) {
    urls.add(lib.toURI().toURL());
}

urls.add(url1);
urls.add(url0);

final URLClassLoader customClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml") {
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader)
    {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
        reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);

        reader.setBeanClassLoader(customClassLoader);
    }
};

allApplicationContexts.add(context1);
```

The Spring contexts start OK, but they fail to create the **component-scan** bean, and **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** isn't working. Everything else seems correct.

I sure my config is correct because it works without the custom classloader. Libs contains all spring lib.

Is it possible to get this working with multiple Spring contexts?